# Error using function setnames: object is not found, but data set has it

Tags: r, data.table

Datasets dt and variables are data.tables.

```
head(dt)
      group      variable  value
     Other        x_3_od     B
     Shops        x_2_od     A
  Supplies        x_3_od     D
     Other        x_1_zr     C
     Other        x_2_od     C
     Shops        x_1_zr     D

head(variables)
      name       labels
      x_1_zr     New Ratio 
      x_2_zr     Ratio 
      x_1_bz     Quality
      x_2_od     Cost
      x_3_od     Balance
```

Variables is a data set with columns *name* and *labels*. Column name has same values as column variable in set dt (but some more) and labels are explanatory names of these codes.
I want to values in column dt$variable change to values from variables$labels. I tried this code:

```
setnames(dt, old = variable, new = variables$labels[match(variable, variables$name)])
```

And got following error:

```
Error in match(variable, variables$name) : 
  object 'variable' not found
```

Also, tried to run the following:

```
setnames(dt, old = variable, new = variables$labels[match(dt$variable, variables$name)])
```

But then got another error:

```
Error in anyDuplicated(old) : object 'variable' not found
```

This is strange because dt does have a column named variable. What could be the reason for this error?

P.S. Updates: datasets with dput, but *dt* has **9000** rows, so only head of it, values of column *variable* are only those which are seen on screen, but repeat many times, possible values of *value* are: A, B, C, D.

```
dt <- structure(list(group = structure(c(12L, 3L, 3L, 12L, 12L, 12L
), levels = c("Automobiles", "Supplies", "Shops", 
"Markets", "Food", "Services", "Leisure", "Pets",
"Materials", "Media", "Other", "Technology", "A", "Bars", "c", "d", "Closed", "f"), class = "factor"), variable = c("x_3_od", 
"x_2_od", "x_3_od ", 
"x_1_zr", "x_2_od", 
"x_1_zr"), value = c("B", "A", "D", "C", 
"C", "D")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
))
    
variables <- structure(list(name = c("x_n_1", "x_n_2", 
"x_1_zr", "x_2_zr", "x_1_bz", 
"x_2_bz", "x_3_od", "x_2_od", 
"x_1_vb", "x_2_vb", "x_3_bz", 
"x_m_2", "x_d_4s", "x_1_od", 
"x_m_3"), labels = c("Houses", 
"Flats", "New Ratio", 
"Ratio", "Quality", 
"Class", "Balance", 
"Cost", "Sales 1", "Sales 2", 
"Terms", "Position", "Duration Average", 
"History", "Others")), row.names = c(NA, 
-15L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), index = structure(integer(0), "`__module`" = c(13L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 14L, 15L)))
```

Comment: Please provide a fully reproducible example for both `dt` and `variables`.

Comment: @s_baldur I added how "variables" dataset looks.

Comment: Can you make it reproducible? You can use `dput()`

Comment: @s_baldur I edited. Only dput of dt is not of full because it has 9000 lines, but I explained in the post what values are possible in columns :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's confusion here, not sure if it's yours or mine. The only thing that `setnames` is going to be doing for `dt` is change one or more of `c("group", "variable", "value")` (the *column* names) to something else. It does nothing to the *contents* of `dt`.

I *think* you are trying to do is update the *values* in the `variable` column based on potentially-matching values in the `variables` table.

Does this do what you intend?

```r
dt[, variable := fcoalesce(variables$labels[match(variable, variables$name)], variable)]
#         group  variable  value
#        <fctr>    <char> <char>
# 1: Technology   Balance      B
# 2:      Shops      Cost      A
# 3:      Shops   x_3_od       D
# 4: Technology New Ratio      C
# 5: Technology      Cost      C
# 6: Technology New Ratio      D
```

And the remaining `"x_3_od "` appears to be because it has a space; if that should have changed to "Balance"`then you can either fix the data before`match`, or match on` trimws`:

```r
dt[, variable := fcoalesce(variables$labels[match(trimws(variable), variables$name)], variable)]
```

For both of those, I inferred that the use of `fcoalesce` was useful: if a match is not found, without `fcoalesce` it would be overwritten with `NA`, the use of `fcoalesce` converts that `NA` back to the original un-match value (as you saw in the first code block).

Another method is in a *join*. Starting with an original dataset:

```r
dt[variables, variable := fcoalesce(i.labels, variable), on = .(variable == name)]
#         group  variable  value
#        <fctr>    <char> <char>
# 1: Technology   Balance      B
# 2:      Shops      Cost      A
# 3:      Shops   x_3_od       D
# 4: Technology New Ratio      C
# 5: Technology      Cost      C
# 6: Technology New Ratio      D
```

Same issue with `"x_3_od "`, though we can't use `trimws` inside of the `on=.(...)` expression, so we'd need to preprocess the spaces out of the data.

Comment: By running this code I got such an error: Error in fcoalesce(variables$labels[match(variable, variables$name)],  : 
  Item 2 is a factor but item 1 is not a factor. When factors are involved, all items must be factor. @r2evans

Comment: But, I tried the second method and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: The error you see seems to indicate that the sample data is not quite the same as your real data; it can likely easily be remedied by using `as.character` to convert from `factor` on whichever one is factors. Glad it works!

Comment: I hope it's clear why `setnames` is not the correct tool for this operation.